# Create folder Structure in Batch using SQL script output

Tags: sql, batch-file

I have a SQL table which holds records which are organised hierarchically as follows:

```
ID Item  OtherColumns ParentID
1   a      blah          NULL
2   b      blah           1
3   c      blah           2
4   d      blah           3
5   e      blah           3
6   f      blah           3
7   g      blah           4
8   h      blah           4
9   i      blah           4
10  j      blah           4
11  k      blah           6
12  l      blah           6
13  m      blah           6
14  n      blah           6
```

Graphically, the hierarchy is

```
a
--b
----c
-------d
----------g
----------h
----------i
----------j
-------e
-------f
----------k
----------l
----------m
----------n
```

I have a SQL script which takes a parentID parameter and returns all the children for that node.

I call the script from a recursive function in a batch file and print out the the items in order of their structure but I'm not sure how I can create a folder structure that mirrors this

My batch is

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 

set Id=1
call :CreateSubDirectories !Id! 1

goto eof

:CreateSubDirectories

    for /f "tokens=1,2,*" %%i IN ('sqlcmd -S MyServer\MyInstance -d myDatabase -U myUser -P myPassword -i C:\Path\to\my\script.sql -v parentId^=%~1! -h -1') DO (
        echo %%i
        call :CreateSubDirectories %%i
    )

:eof

endlocal
```

so this prints out

```
a
b
c
d
g
h
i
j
e
f
k
l
m
n
```

however, if i was to add a mkdir to my loop, all the folders would create on the same level. How can I get this create the folder structure represented above?

Comment: have you some CTE code already?

Comment: Yes, the SQL script has a recursive CTE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run the mkdir against a CTE output

```
DECLARE @foo TABLE
(ID int, Item  varchar(100), OtherColumns varchar(20), ParentID int)

INSERT @foo VALUES
(1   ,'a', 'blah', NULL),
(2   ,'b', 'blah',  1  ),
(3   ,'c', 'blah',  2  ),
(4   ,'d', 'blah',  3  ),
(5   ,'e', 'blah',  3  ),
(6   ,'f', 'blah',  3  ),
(7   ,'g', 'blah',  4  ),
(8   ,'h', 'blah',  4  ),
(9   ,'i', 'blah',  4  ),
(10  ,'j', 'blah',  4  ),
(11  ,'k', 'blah',  6  ),
(12  ,'l', 'blah',  6  ),
(13  ,'m', 'blah',  6  ),
(14  ,'n', 'blah',  6  );

WITH Hierarchy AS
(
    SELECT ID, FolderPath = Item, OtherColumns, ParentID, 1 AS Level FROM @foo WHERE ParentID IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT [@foo].ID,
           LEFT(CONCAT(Hierarchy.FolderPath, '\', [@foo].Item), 100),
           [@foo].OtherColumns,
           [@foo].ParentID,
           Level + 1
    FROM 
        Hierarchy JOIN @foo ON [@foo].ParentID = Hierarchy.ID

)
SELECT FolderPath FROM Hierarchy ORDER BY Hierarchy.Level;
```

gives

```
a
a\b
a\b\c
a\b\c\d
a\b\c\e
a\b\c\f
a\b\c\f\k
a\b\c\f\l
a\b\c\f\m
a\b\c\f\n
a\b\c\d\g
a\b\c\d\h
a\b\c\d\i
a\b\c\d\j
```